# Some Page not working in polylang plugin wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual, polylang

I have install and active polylang plugin then i have add english_US language then i am checking my website in this some page are working fine but some are not working throw me error This page isn’t working. if i deactive plugin then all working fine.

Is there any other solution or some other plugin available for free same as polylang ?.

Below is the error page

[image]

Comment: Have you check your console ? or network error ? which kind of error you have faced please mention here.

Comment: Dear i didn't get any error in console its just redirect me to page with error This page isn’t working i have add screen shot in my question

Comment: so is there any permalink issue ? have you tested with change permalink setting after you active the plugin?

Comment: Yes i have check with permalink first set to plain and save and then set to post and save but not get success

Comment: have you any caching plugin also de-active these plugin otherwise clear cache while you hit URL

Comment: dear i have disable my caching plugin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197245/discussion-between-er-nilay-parekh-and-dhruv).